Can we get tighter upper bound of $\frac{pd^2(d^{2i}-p^i)}{d^2-p}\le 2pd^{2i}$?
Let $d>1$ be a large enough integer. Let $p:=[\sqrt{\frac{d}{\log d}}]$. I read one paper and it says that the summation of the following geometric sequence with ratio $p/d^2$ for $i\ge 1$,
$$
p(d)^{2i}+p^2(d)^{2(i-1)}+\dots+p^{i-1}d^4+p^id^2=\frac{pd^2(d^{2i}-p^i)}{d^2-p}?
$$
I know that how to get this summation but how to get upper bound
$$
\frac{pd^2(d^{2i}-p^i)}{d^2-p}\le 2pd^{2i}
$$

(It seems that the above inequality is equivalent to
$$
0\le d^{2i}+p^i-2pd^{2i-2}=d^{2i}+(\frac{d}{\log d})^{i/2}-2(\frac{d}{\log d})^{1/2}d^{2i-2}.
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
2d^{2i-3/2}(\log d)^{i/2}\le d^{2i}(\log d)^{i/2}+d^{i/2}
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
2d^{3(i-1)/2}(\log d)^{i/2}\le d^{3i/2}(\log d)^{i/2}+1
$$
)
Moreover, can we get better upper bound? I feel that this upper bound is too loose...

Let the geometric ratio $q =p/d^2$.  Since $p=[\sqrt{\frac{d}{\log d}}]$, we have $q=[\sqrt{\frac{1}{d^3\log d}}]\le 0.5$ for $d \ge 2$.
Now  observe
$$
p(d)^{2i}+p^2(d)^{2(i-1)}+\dots+p^{i-1}d^4+p^id^2=\frac{pd^{2i}(1-q^i)}{1-q}
$$
We want  to establish
$$
\frac{p(d)^{2i}(1-q^i)}{1-q} \le 2pd^{2i} 
$$
or
$$
1+q^i  \ge 2 q
$$
which, for all $i$, is true for $q \le 0.5$ which holds (see above) for $d>1$. So we are done with the proof. $\square$
Better bounds? Well, the factor which is dropping for larger $d$ and $i$ very fast is $q^i$. The other proportionalities stay in place.  So a better bound  - which will hardly be improved - would be
$$
\frac{p(d)^{2i}(1-q^i)}{1-q} \le \frac{p(d)^{2i}}{1-q} = \frac{p(d)^{2(i+1)}}{d^2-p}
$$

But why this bound in the last display is better? Do we have $pd^{2i+2}/(d^2-p)\le 2pd^{2i}$?

Yes, the bound is better. Since $1/(1-q) \le 2$ for $q < 0.5$, which is what we have (see above). Indeed, $q$ will be FAR smaller than $0.5$ as $d$ rises.
